# Delete Project from team foundation server on visualstudio.com

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure-devops

I was trying to delete project from [Team Foundation Service](http://visualstudio.com) and I am getting this error:

> TF200016: The following project does not exist: PetraERP_1. Verify
>   that the name  of the project is correct and that the project exists
>   on the specified Team Foundation Server.

The command which I used is:

```
TFSDeleteProject /force /collection:https://mydomain.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection  PetraERP_1
```

The project path is `$/Petra Solutions/PetraERP_1`.

[image]

Comment: I realize the nomenclature is bad here, but `PetraERP_1` is a *Visual Studio Project*, it's not a *Team Project*.

Comment: As a note - in TFS 2013 deleting a project is possible from the Admin console so the command line command is not needed

Answer (score 4):

`Petra Solutions` is the team project name.

Deleting this will remove **all** your code, work items, builds, everything! And it is **not** recoverable.

If that is the case then, there is an option in the Web Access to do that now.

Or via the command line:

```
TFSDeleteProject /force /collection:https://mydomain.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection "Petra Solutions"
```

If that is not the case, and you just want to delete the `PetraERP_1` folder of code, you want the [`tf delete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k45zb450.aspx) command line to delete the source code only (this is recoverable).

To use `tf delete` you need to have a working copy of the code checked out. You can do a non-recursive checkout with the `tf get` command in a Workspace with a mapping to that path.

Comment: i don't want to delete the complete project name , only specific folder , i solved it you should map the complete solution "Petra Solutions" and then you can delete it